Aligning different curves for comparison in matplotlib
I'm working on a project to compare the execution times of different algorithms with their theoretical time complexities in Python. Specifically, I'm testing three versions of a prime number checking function, each with a different theoretical complexity:

v1: O(n)

v2: O(n/2)

v3: O(sqrt(n))


For each algorithm, I plot both the actual execution time and the theoretical time complexity on the same graph. I aim to visually match the shape and scale of the theoretical curves with the empirical execution times. However, I'm facing issues with aligning these curves correctly, particularly with scaling each theoretical complexity curve individually.
# Sample data
test_list = np.array([...])  # Input sizes
times_v1 = np.array([...])  # Execution times for v1
times_v2 = np.array([...])  # Execution times for v2
times_v3 = np.array([...])  # Execution times for v3


# For v1: O(n)
C_v1 = times_v1[0] / test_list[0]
theoretical_v1 = [(x)/C_v1 for x in test_list]

# For v2: O(n/2)
C_v2 = times_v2[0] / (test_list[0] / 2)
theoretical_v2 = [(x/2)/C_v1 for x in test_list]

# For v3: O(√n)
C_v3 = times_v3[0] / test_list[0]
# This should correctly represent O(√n)
theoretical_v3 = [np.sqrt(x)/C_v1 for x in test_list]
# Plotting
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 8))

# Actual execution times
plt.plot(test_list, times_v1, 'o-', label="v1: O(n)", color="blue")

# Theoretical complexities
plt.plot(test_list, theoretical_v1, '--',
         label="Theoretical O(n)", color="blue")


plt.xlabel("Input Size (n)")
plt.ylabel("Time (ms)")
plt.title("Prime Number Check: Execution Time vs Theoretical Complexity")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

plt.plot(test_list, times_v2, 'o-', label="v2: O(n/2)", color="green")
plt.plot(test_list, theoretical_v2, '--',
         label="Theoretical O(n/2)", color="green")
plt.xlabel("Input Size (n)")
plt.ylabel("Time (ms)")
plt.title("Prime Number Check: Execution Time vs Theoretical Complexity")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

plt.plot(test_list, times_v3, 'o-', label="v3: O(√n)", color="red")
plt.plot(test_list, theoretical_v3, '--',
         label="Theoretical O(√n)", color="red")
plt.xlabel("Input Size (n)")
plt.ylabel("Time (ms)")
plt.title("Prime Number Check: Execution Time vs Theoretical Complexity")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

When I run the code above, the alignment between the theoretical and empirical curves isn’t as consistent as when I used fixed constants (like 9999, 7532, and 1000) for scaling the theoretical values. It seems that the dynamic scaling factors calculated from the initial data points don’t fully capture the overall trend, especially as the input sizes grow.
Is there a way to consistently scale the theoretical curves dynamically across the entire input range without resorting to hardcoded constants? Or is there a standard practice for handling such scaling issues?

There is no "standard" way, but you can perform a least absolute error fit on the curves to get, theoretical_scaled = a * theoretical such that it is closest to actual ...
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def objective_function(params, actual, theoretical):
    a = params
    return np.sum(np.abs(actual - (a * theoretical)))


x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
actual = np.array([1, 4, 7, 8, 10])
theoretical = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

initial_guess = np.array([1])
result = minimize(objective_function, initial_guess, args=(actual, theoretical))
a_opt = result.x

theoretical_scaled = a_opt * theoretical

plt.plot(x, actual, label="actual")
plt.plot(x, theoretical_scaled, label="theoretical")
plt.legend()
plt.show()


There are books about different normalization methods and norms to use to make this more "appealing", but this looks fine, i would prefer L1 norm here because it allows some values to be incorrect, while the L2 norm is very susceptible to outliers, you can even try norms below 1 to see improvements in some cases.
you can also play with different fitting functions, for example you can make it theoretical_scaled = a * theoretical + b where b is an offset, etc..

Thx , that worked very well
